# Stop OS X From Auto-Pasting Clipboard Text Into "Find" Field

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Whenever I have text copied to my clipboard, this text gets auto-pasted into the field of the "Find" command (Command + F) with no interaction from me. I don't like this behavior, as most of the time that is not what I wanted to search for and then I have to go in and delete it before I can search. Even if there is already text there from a previous search, the clipboard text will replace it when I hit Command + F.

This happens to me in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, TextEdit, Sublime, Keynote, Pages, and Numbers but not in Microsoft applications like Outlook and Word. These are just the apps I've tested, I don't know about others, but I can check if that becomes relevant.

I am on OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). This occurs on both my desktop and my laptop, so it's not isolated to one computer. Both computers are running El Capitan (upgraded from Yosemite via the App Store, so no weird installers) but other than that have fairly different setups/app installations.

Does anyone know how to disable or prevent this? I found [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1055853) to someone asking a similar question about Firefox, but their solution (an extension) only applied to Firefox copying text selected in Firefox.

I don't have any utilities related to the keyboard installed or any keyboard remapping or even any custom shortcuts at all.

Comment: The link you provided is unrelated - apparently if you highlight text and then hit Command-F in Firefox, it will automatically input the highlighted text into the Find field. As far as your question, I have never seen that happen before. Do you have any utilities installed that might have this kind of functionality? Do you have any keyboard remapping set up (in Karabiner, etc.) that might auto-paste after you hit Command-F? This is not default (or even optional) behavior in OS X itself.

Comment: The solution may not be relevant but the question in the link specifically says: "When opening/focusing the "Find in page" field (Cmd + F), my **clipboard content** is automatically pasted in the field." This was the only instance I could find of someone with a similar problem, so I'm going to leave it in.

I don't have any utilities related to the keyboard installed or any remapping or even any custom shortcuts at all. This occurs on both my desktop and my laptop, so it's not isolated to one computer. Adding some info about this to the question.

Comment: If you continue reading the page you are referring to, the result is the user was confused and the behavior I described in my previous comment was actually the cause. That said, that is not the cause in Chrome (AFAIK). I don't use the other two apps you tested.

Comment: This is normal behavior for macOS, assuming that the values being pasted are your previous search strings, not the previously copied string.  That is, in addition to the "general pasteboard" there is a "find pasteboard" (and others, such as the "drag" and "font" pasteboards).  For example, the following happens for me: 1. in Firefox, highlight `clipboard text` and hit ⌘C; 2. hit ⌘F and search for `ff find`; 3. open iTerm and hit ⌘F, it autofills the find field with `ff find` and leaves it highlighted; 4. still in iTerm, I hit ⌘V and now I see `clipboard text`.